# Eclipse error: <class name> cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I think this is a simple question, for someone. Pretty straight-forward.

I have my own workspace that I'm tinkering with to learn Java. I created a simple class called Customer. 3 attributes, 3 getters and 3 setter methods.

I then created a class called CustomerTester with a  main method to instantiate Customer and test it's methods.

I've created both of these in the same workspace.

However, when I finished writing CustomerTester and have the line to to instantiate my Customer class, the editor is saying:
"Customer cannot be resolved to a type".

I'm sure it's some type of environment setup, but not sure what.

When I complete these 2 classes in Textpad, I have no issues and my tester class runs just fine.

Can someone help, please?

Thanks,
Jim.

```
 public class Customer { 
       //Attribute definitions private 
       String name; private String address; 
       private String phoneNbr; 

       //Getter methods 
       public String getName() { 
          return name; 
       } 

       public String getAddress() { 
          return address; 
       } 
       public String getPhoneNbr() { 
          return phoneNbr; 
       } 

       //Setter methods 
       public void setName(String newName) { 
          name = newName; 
       } 
       public void setAddress(String newAddress) { 
          address = newAddress; 
       } 
       public void setPhoneNbr(String newPhoneNbr) { 
          phoneNbr = newPhoneNbr; 
       } 
   } 

public class CustomerTester { 

   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      //Create Customer instance 
      Customer aCustomer = new Customer(); 
      //Invoke Customer Setter methods
      aCustomer.setName("James A Johnson"); 
      aCustomer.setAddress("17945 Tyler street NW Elk River, MN"); 
      aCustomer.setPhoneNbr("952-270-1643"); 

     //Create variables to retrieve Customer values via Getter methods 
     String customerName, customerAddress, customerPhoneNbr;

     //Invoke Customer Getter methods 
     customerName = aCustomer.getName(); 
     customerAddress = aCustomer.getAddress();
     customerPhoneNbr = aCustomer.getPhoneNbr();
```

Comment: Are both classes in same package (folder) ?

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: Show us the tree of your workspace. You should certainly import your Customer class. CTRL+MAJ+O

Comment: I can't import it since it can't find it:

Comment: Both are in the same folder - c:\users\jim\workspace

Comment: public class Customer
{
 //Attribute definitions
 private String name;
 private String address;
 private String phoneNbr;
 
 //Getter methods
 public String getName()
 {
  return name;
 }
 public String getAddress()
 {
  return address;
 }
 public String getPhoneNbr()
 {
  return phoneNbr;
 }
 
 //Setter methods
 public void setName(String newName)
 {
  name = newName;
 }
 public void setAddress(String newAddress)
 {
  address = newAddress;
 }
 public void setPhoneNbr(String newPhoneNbr)
 {
  phoneNbr = newPhoneNbr;
 }
}

Comment: public class CustomerTester {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Create Customer instance
  Customer aCustomer = new Customer();
  
  //Invoke Customer Setter methods
  aCustomer.setName("James A Johnson");
  aCustomer.setAddress("17945 Tyler street NW Elk River, MN");
  aCustomer.setPhoneNbr("952-270-1643");
  
  //Create variables to retrieve Customer values via Getter methods
  String customerName, customerAddress, customerPhoneNbr;
  
  //Invoke Customer Getter methods
  customerName = aCustomer.getName();
  customerAddress = aCustomer.getAddress();

Comment: There's one more Getter method, but it's too long to paste in here

Comment: The whole class, that is: customerPhoneNbr = aCustomer.getPhoneNbr();

Comment: "You need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits". I can't see suggested edits.

Answer (score 1):

ctrl + shift + O to import all the packages. See if that works

Comment: YES! That seemed to do it. It did ask what to import - bin or src.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the project and pasted it in the workspace( creating a new project with the same data) and it got resolved for me.